# How do I create an OpenMaya UI?

Tags: c++, python, api, maya, pymel

I don't know how to create a UI with MayaApi, all I have done in the past is something like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
winWidth = 400
if pm.window("window", exists=1): pm.deleteUI("window")
pm.window("window", w=winWidth)   
with pm.columnLayout('content', adjustableColumn=True):             
    with pm.rowColumnLayout(nc=1):
        pm.text(l="wooo! A window! ")
```

However, is there a way to create a UI without the use of pymel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pyqt designer to create a GUI, then pyuic4 to convert it into python.  From there you can setup your callbacks and signals in python.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.geoffsamuel.com/Tutorials/Intro_Maya_QT.php

Or use the maya.cmds and create your windows and buttons with the built in qt features of maya

Comment: Ive used pyqt before but didnt know you could convert it to python, thats awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing something pretty hardcore - like you need to do custom openGL drawing in a 3d view - the complexity and potential drawbacks of doing ordinary UI in the API directly outweigh the pluses. Python will be slower - but probably not in ways that users notice. And it's much harder to force-exit your maya with a typo in Python than in the API :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/API/group___open_maya_u_i.html). Autodesk has it's own docs for this.